# Pytorch getting accuracy of train_loop doesn't work

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I want to get the accuracy of my train section of my neuronal network
But i get this error:
correct += (prediction.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).item()
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
With this code :

```
def train_loop(dataloader, model, optimizer):
    model.train()
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    correct = 0, 0
    l_loss = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        prediction = model(X)
        loss = cross_entropy(prediction, y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        correct += (prediction.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
        loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
        l_loss = loss
        print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
    correct /= size
    accu = 100 * correct

    train_loss.append(l_loss)
    train_accu.append(accu)
    print(f"Accuracy: {accu:>0.1f}%")
```

I don't understand why it is not working becaus in my test section it work perfektly fine with execly the same code line.

Comment: You're missing the `sum` in your question but it is present in your code block. Is it actually summed? Also, I would remove the `item` call.

Comment: @jhso still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` function is used to convert a `one-element tensor` to a standard python number as stated in the [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html#torch-tensor-item). Please try to make sure that the result of the `sum()` is only a one-element tensor before using `item()`.

```
x = torch.tensor([1.0,2.0]) # a tensor contains 2 elements
x.item()
```

error message: `ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars`

Try to use this:

```
prediction = prediction.argmax(1)
correct = prediction.eq(y)
correct = correct.sum() 
print(correct) # to check if it is a one value tensor
correct_sum += correct.item()
```

Comment: Now i get this error:
    correct_sum += correct.item()
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: This error in which line?

Comment: But has the first error message been solved?

Comment: WEll in line  correct_sum += correct.item() or what do you mean?

Comment: yes the first one seams tpo be solved

Comment: Ok, what was the output of the print(correct)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242106/discussion-between-phoenix-and-johann-verlohren).

Comment: nvm i solved it

Comment: Great, well done! What was it?

Comment: It was because i when i called correct outside of the loop i said correct = 0, 0 but it had to be 0